# Linux Mint - Issues when executing scripts through Geany

Tags: linux-mint, geany

I'm using Geany to write and execute some simple scripts in Python and I've been running into a really annoying issue lately. Occasionaly, after running the same script for a few times, the application stops working. Hitting the "run or view the current file" does nothing. Not even a terminal pops up, it's like I never clicked anything. The only thing I can do is edit code. It happens after 10-15 minutes of working and the only thing that seems to fix it is restarting my computer. Any ideas?

I'm running Linux Mint 18.3 and Geany 1.27

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Terminal is not *available*, then you need to go to the prompt, hit `enter` or `Ctrl+C` to liberate it.
By default you have a message in *state-bar* (bottom down), here in French :
[image]

My conf, Geany 1.28, LMDE2